# Case when no record then error (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql-9.1

Struggling with a simple problem and find no solution.

https://ideone.com/Hisu8H (sqlfiddle mini) Should be two rows, but only one OK appears.

If there is a record there should be an OK result. If no records there should be ERROR result.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) from code)=0 THEN 'ERROR' else 'OK' end
FROM code
WHERE "CODE_ID"='EXISTS'
```

The problem is that if the CODE_ID exists, there will be a line OK but if the record is missing there will be no line fetched at all.

In a simple query this works. But not as a condition!

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(*), 0) FROM code
WHERE "CODE_ID"='ERROR'
```

Thanks in advance for any clue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no row that matches the condition then nothing is returned and you can't count it.

To return information about values that are used in a condition but do not exist in the database you typically use an outer join on the list of values:

```
select t.id, 
       code.code_id
from (
  values ('error'), ('test')
) as t (id) 
  left join code on code.code_id = t.id;
```

This essentially a `where code_id in ('error', 'test')` query that also returns those values from the `in` list that do not exist in the table.

This can then be used to identify the missing values:

```
select t.id, 
       case when code.code_id is null then 'Error' else 'OK' end as status
from (
  values ('error'), ('test')
) as t (id) 
  left join code on code.code_id = t.id;
```

Comment: I now understand why my code not work. Thank you! But I cannot get your code to work. Is there no simple way to "case when ifnull(code_id) then x else y"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "simple way". `case when code_id is null then x else y end` seems to be exactly what you want.   Sorry, "*cannot get your code to work*" is not an acceptable problem description. My statement works just fine with the table and sample data you provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e840f/2